How to convert RTCVideoFrame to YUV in webrtc iOS
This is my code, the converted yuv rendering is sometimes normal, sometimes not normal, is there any problem?
    func convertRTCVideoFrameToYUV(frame: RTCVideoFrame) -> (yData: Data, uData: Data, vData: Data) {
        
        let i420Buffer = frame.buffer.toI420()
        
        let width = Int(i420Buffer.width)
        let height = Int(i420Buffer.height)
        
        let ySize = Int(width * height)
        
//        let uvWidth = (width + 1) / 2
//        let uvHeight = (height + 1) / 2
        
//        let uSize = Int(uvWidth * uvHeight)
//        let vSize = Int(uvWidth * uvHeight)
        let uSize = Int((width / 2) * (height / 2))
        let vSize = Int((width / 2) * (height / 2))
        
        var yData = Data(count: ySize)
        var uData = Data(count: uSize)
        var vData = Data(count: vSize)
        
        yData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { yBuffer in
            guard let yPtr = yBuffer.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else { return }
            let yPlane = i420Buffer.dataY
            memcpy(yPtr, yPlane, ySize)
        }
        
        uData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { uBuffer in
            guard let uPtr = uBuffer.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else { return }
            let uPlane = i420Buffer.dataU
            memcpy(uPtr, uPlane, uSize)
        }
        
        vData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { vBuffer in
            guard let vPtr = vBuffer.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) else { return }
            let vPlane = i420Buffer.dataV
            memcpy(vPtr, vPlane, vSize)
        }
        
//        adjustForRotation(&yData, &uData, &vData, width, height, frame.rotation)

        return (yData, uData, vData)
    }

I have tried many conversion methods, but can not find the problem of rendering flower screen

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
